# Custom List View isn't responding to itemClickListener

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a custom List view in which I have a `textview` and an `ImageView`. I have set `focusable= false` for both textView and ImageView. For the list view I am using a custom array adapter which extends `ArrayAdapter<ApplicationInfo>`. The problem is the list items are not firing item click listener no matter what. I know it is very embarassing to be unable to figure out this problem but I have spent almost 2 hours on this but couldn't solve. Here is the code:

In `onCreate()`

```
list = getListView();
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(MyApp.this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
});
```

I have tried this way also but still I am unable to get clicks.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Toast.makeText(this, "dfdsf",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

What possibly can be the reason for this weird issue? I have worked with CustomListViews in the past but never came across this problem.

```
    list.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(MyAppsList.this, appList, pManager));
```

Comment: You can try adding a `View.OnClickListener` in your Adapter's `getView` method.

Comment: What is in getView() method?

Comment: try making imageView and TextView focusable true, that might help as the events are fired and passed between manager view and their respective parents in a zigzag manner. making it false might just stop the flow of control.. and yes as beworker mentioned what is in the getView()

Comment: addng View.OnClickListener inside getView in the Adapter might work but then it involves overhead or infuses complexity and unwanted behaviour making it difficult for testing

Answer (score 1):

if you ussing just an Activity use the next code for get you list view:

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.your_list);
```

And when you use **ListActivity** you get your ListView by calling method

```
ListView list = getListView();
```

or you can use

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.your_list)
```

Try to use **findViewById** insted of **getListView**().

HTH.